# Inconsistent header and column widths in IE8

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

In IE8 the columns and headers of my Table are not working correctly. The columns are getting just the space they need for the widest data inside of them, and the columns seem to get their original size. When I click or resize the column headers, things are acting up even more.

Also, I have a lot of rows (more than 1000) in my table, but no scrollbar appears, so I can't even see all the data.

[image: IE8 width problem] Here's an image of what it looks like in IE8.

For the record, everything works just fine in Chrome, Firefox and IE9 (probably in IE10 as well, but haven't got the chance to test it).

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You have hopefully fixed this however I have the same problem with inconsistent column widths, if you do have a solution then i'd be very grateful.

What I can help you with is your scroll bar issue.  For the table to have a scroll bar it needs to have a fixed height, this can either be .setSizeFull() on the table and .setExpandRatio(table,1) on the layout (vertical or horizontal), or it could be from .setHeight("XYZpx/%").  Remember setSizeFull and percentage heights on the table require that either all of the parent layouts are setSizeFull (or a percentage) or that is true at least until there is a layout defined with a height in px.

If in doubt take a look at the browser developer tools (hit F12 in most browsers, in Firefox, you'll need Firebug installed), seeing the css affecting the elements is very useful, it's most useful to see the element level styles though, these are set though the JAVA code and if you're having problems with a setSizeFull somewhere then it can really help you locate how far up the chain it is, put marker styles on your layouts if you need to to understand it better (using .addStyleName("ImWhatYouAreLookingFor")).

Comment: Unfortunately I have not been able to fix this issue. The requirement of the project in question have IE9 as minimum requirement, so I have down prioritized this bug. However, when I get some time over to fix it I will take your comments into consideration and I will certainly get back with an answer! Thanks Andrew!